# Leave out views Android XML Runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments, openvpn

I am using this app as a source for my company's personal OpenVPN App: [ICS-OpenVPN](https://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/)
And I want to use the existing about-page and add a couple of my own links. However, these links are only available when you're connected to our local network. Is there any way I can remove the links from the page if the user is not connected to that network?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

For anyone else having this question.